# How do I manage locations for the Reminders iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, reminders

I want to manage where my home, work etc is for the reminders app.

Where can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your home and work geo-location are picked up from your contacts card in the Contacts app (on iOS devices). To manage where your home or work is, edit the relevant addresses in the Contacts app, under 'add new address'.

[image]

You can also edit other peoples addresses, add shops, the gym, clubs, etc, and it will use this data.